# How to delete an element in jQuery with a specific child?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<p><br style="clear:both;"></p>
```

I'm using the Wikipedia API for a project, and I'm cleaning up Wikipedia's raw HTML output and I've been struggling with this problem.  How do I remove this specific `<p>` element from the DOM with jQuery using `.remove();`? I only want the `<p>` element with `<br style="clear:both;">` inside of it to be removed.

Thanks in advance! I've been struggling with this problem.

Comment: <<I only want the 'p' element with inside of it to be removed>> You mean to remove the p tag or its content (br) ?

Comment: I meant to remove the p tag and all of it's content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose the child is `br` itself, then the code will be -

```
$('p>br').closest('p').remove();
```

or use

```
$('p>br[style="clear:both;"]').closest('p').remove();
```

or use the parent function

```
$('br[style="clear:both;"]').parent('p').remove();
```

but **don't** make it

```
$('br[style="clear:both;"]').parent().remove(); // Don't use this
```

because there may be many `br` possible in the `dom` whose parent is not `p`

Comment: Note that this will remove all `p` tags that contains a `br`, even if it doesn’t contain the style declaration. You should have been clear about that in the question.

Comment: @RohitAgrawal weird.. somehow doesn't work.. only removes the style attribute.

Comment: are you sure @FalkoJoseph ??

Comment: @FalkoJoseph see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711187/how-to-delete-an-element-in-jquery-with-a-specific-child/17711605#17711605)

Answer (score 5):

So, you're trying to remove all elements that directly contain a `<br>` with the given style attribute?

```
$('br[style="clear:both;"]').parent().remove();
```

This is decently conservative in that it only matches `br` tags of the form you describe—though it might be worth being even *more* conservative by sticking a `p` selector in that `parent` call. But, it's also sufficiently conservative that it might not catch small variations on this markup, so keep an eye out.

Comment: Doesn't work, now it has '<p><br></p>' instead. It only removed the style attribute.

Comment: Hm. This code definitely won't remove a style attribute, so it sounds like this appeared elsewhere and there are multiple types of things you want to remove—I was afraid of that :/ You might need more rules, or might want to find a more general way to express what you want to do.

Comment: Also, check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17711253/107415) with the pretty `:has` syntax—its behavior is slightly different, but it also better expresses the code's intent.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$('p:has(br[style="clear:both;"])').remove();
```

[**<kbd>JSBin Demo</kbd>**](http://jsbin.com/uziniv/1/edit)

As Matchu pointed out be careful as this will remove `<p>` elements with `<br  style="clear:both;">` inside, so in certain specific cases (if there's anything else inside the `<p>`) it could remove more than you expect...

Comment: Ooh, I like this one better. TIL. Be aware that this will remove more than you expect if there are nested `p` tags—but, who does that, anyway? I'd be interested in how performance compares, too, and whether it tries to select on `br` and check the parent or whether it selects on `p` and checks the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p').filter(function(i) {
    return $(this).children('br').css('clear') == 'both';
}).remove();
```

Comment: That would do the trick, but how does filter compare to has, performance wise?

Comment: @FalkoJoseph set up a jsperf if you want to know more about browser performance, or ask a new question. I would say that it’s a matter of coding preference in the end - perfection kills.

Comment: Good question. Let us know when you've got an answer.

Answer (score 0):

the much safer method to do the task -

```
$('p').each(function(){
    if($(this).children().length === $(this).children('br').length)
      $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p').each(function(){
    if($(this).children('br').length == 1) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

This worked for me. It seems 'clear:both;' was generated by the browser. Thanks for all the ideas and suggestions so I could figure this out!